# AVFoundation - macOS - 2 cameras simultaneous recording with compression

Tags: macos, performance, video, avfoundation, video-capture

I'm programming *video capturing app* and need to have 2 input sources (USB cams) to record from at the same time.

When I record only the raw footage simultaneously without compression at is working quite well (Low CPU load, no video lags), but when the compression is turned on the CPU is very high and the footage is lagging.

How to solve it? Or how to tune-up the settings so that it can be accomplished?

Note: the Raw streams are to big and thus cannot be used, otherwise I would not bother with compression at all and just leave it as it is.

Comment: Reduce the compression rate? Multithread?

Comment: Well compression is not so big, and the both Qeues are concurrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AVFoundation framework in its current configuration is setup to provide HW acceleration only for one source at time. For multiple accelerated sources one need to go deeper to VideoToolbox framework and even deeper.